# Orchard CMS - Pass data between local zones

Tags: orchardcms

In a list row template I need to know if a row field value matches the previous row's to toggle some HTML.  How should I go about this?

I've tried caching the key in ViewBag, but that doesn't persist across the sibling zones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest would probably be to override the List shape rendering (see http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/03/27/taking-over-list-rendering-in-orchard.aspx) and add the information you need on each item shape on the fly.

Comment: Thanks, Bertrand.  For other's reading this - in my list template, I got my list items from Model.List.Items, then iterated over the items and set item.MyDynamicProperty = value

Comment: For 'item.MyDynamicProperty = value' to work, you'll need to have the 'URL Alternates' and/or 'Widget Alternates' enabled, though I'm not clear why.  When I turned these modules off, my (alternate) template was still invoked, but I got a runtime error stating MyDynamicProperty didn't exist.